# Determine the mean and variance of X

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution

Suppose that the number of customers who enter a post office in a 32-minute period is a Poisson random variable and that $P(X = 0) = 0.12$

How would I find the mean and variance in this case? I feel like I don't have enough info but am most likely missing something obvious.

Comment: If this is a question from a course or a textbook, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution Do you see the Pr(X=K) in the page?

Comment: You've been given k (which is zero) and the probability. Solve it to the lamda. The lamda is the mean and variance. Poisson has the same mean and variance.

Comment: So is the left hand side of the equation going to be .12 and then I just need to isolate the $\lambda$?

Comment: @StudentT I figured it out. Thanks for the help. I wasn't sure what lambda was representing in this case.

Comment: @Slae consider posting an outline of your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $P(X=0)$ as the pmf evaluated at 0.

This gives $P(X=0)$ as a function of the parameter.

You can solve for that parameter, and use the relation between the parameter and the mean and variance of a Poisson to give the answer to the question.